# PostGIS accuracy of ST_DWithin results

Tags: postgis

I'm testing a function in a PostGIS spatial database: `ST_DWithin`. On edge cases I sometimes get `true` and sometimes `false`.

```
SELECT ST_DWithin(
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90.01 30)','4326'),
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90 30)','4326'),
    '0.01'
)
st_dwithin -> false
```

and

```
SELECT ST_DWithin(
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90.1 30)','4326'),
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90 30)','4326'),
    '0.1'
)
st_dwithin -> true
```

Shouldn't both be either true or false? Can anybody explain the results to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that underlying computations uses double precision and not the exact numeric type. Therefore, the computed distance between points is accurate up to 15 digits only.

```
Select ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90.01 30)','4326'),
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90 30)','4326')) d1,
    ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90.1 30)','4326'),
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90 30)','4326')) d2;
==>
         d1         |         d2
--------------------+--------------------
 0.0100000000000051 | 0.0999999999999943
(1 row)
```

We can see that both computed distances are inexact. Moreover, floating point equality comparison should always consider the precision. If not done, we get unexpected results (like `d1 > .01 and d2 < .1`)

You can read Postgresql doc on [floats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) and google *floating point comparison*